# no template exists message and xsl:with-param cannot appear as a child of xsl:template message

Tags: xml, templates, xslt

I have a stylesheet that I am close to being valid but for some reason I have multiple of the "no template exists" and "xsl:with-param cannot appear as a child of xsl:template" messages appearing.

There is a major one of the whole document failing to compile as well.

Here is the xsl

```
    <xsl:template match="calcScores">
        <xsl:with-param name="currentRound" />
        <xsl:with-param name="currentHole" />
        <xsl:variable name="parTotal" select="sum(//par[@holeNumber &lt;= @currentHole])" /> 
            <xsl:variable name="golferTotal" select="sum(@currentRound/score[@holeNumber &lt; currentHole])" />    <!-- look at <= here -->
        <xsl:variable name="currentScore" select="parTotal - golferTotal" /> 
        <xsl:variable name="currentScoreText" >
            <xsl:call-template name="formatScore">
                <xsl:with-param name="scoreValue" select="@currentScore"></xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:variable>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="currentScoreText"/></td>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="currentHole=18">
                    <xsl:variable name="backNinePar" select="sum(//par[@holeNumber > 9 and @holeNumber &lt; 18])"></xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:variable name="backNineGolfer" select="sum(@currentRound/score[@holeNumber > 9 and @holeNumber &lt;= 18])"></xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:variable name="backNineScore." select="backNinePar - backNineGolfer"></xsl:variable>
                    <xsl:variable name="backNineScoreText" >
                        <xsl:call-template name="formatScore">
                            <xsl:with-param name="scoreValue" select="@backNineScore"></xsl:with-param>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:variable>
                </xsl:when>
                <xsl:when test="currentHole=9">
                    <td class="sub">$currentScoreText</td>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:if test="@currentHole &lt; 18">
            <xsl:call-template name="calcScores">
                <xsl:with-param name="currentRound" select="@currentRound"></xsl:with-param>
                <xsl:with-param name="currentHole" select="@currentHole+1"></xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template> 
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="formatHole">
    <xsl:with-param name="holeScore" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@holeScore &lt; @parScore" >
                <td class="low">holeScore</td>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="holeScore > parScore" >
                <td class="high">holeScore</td>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <td>holeScore</td>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part

```
 <xsl:template match="calcScores">
        <xsl:with-param name="currentRound" />
        <xsl:with-param name="currentHole" />
```

is wrong, it needs to be

```
 <xsl:template match="calcScores">
        <xsl:param name="currentRound" />
        <xsl:param name="currentHole" />
```

or perhaps

```
 <xsl:template name="calcScores">
        <xsl:param name="currentRound" />
        <xsl:param name="currentHole" />
```